# Load common content for the whole Django site

Tags: django, django-views

I want to load a list notifications for almost all the web application I am building. Should I do in every view function or View Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not, Django provides several mechanisms to take care of that kind of issues.

**[Context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)** are functions that are called each time a template is rendered and which output populates that template's context. They allow you to have the same variables available everywhere in your templates.

**[Custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)** and especially [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) allow you to output content anywhere in a template by just calling them, which is as simple as `{% my_tag_name %}`.

These two mechanism coupled with template [inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) and [inclusion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include) allow you to not repeat code that is shared across many pages.